# React-Native : messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp not calling after I quit my app

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native

I have implemented rnfirebase cloud messaging from and implemented everything as mentioned in https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage. I am receiving the calls in messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp and getInitialNotification() but only until I quit my app. Once I quit my app, I never receive the callbacks of notification clicks. Notification simply opens the app. (I am not using any Splash screen)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same problem...

Comment: React Native upgrade and Firebase npm update fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve by upgrading React Native version and updating firebase npm.